# How to make a Raku test optional if a module is not installed

Tags: raku

I am adding a feature to a package that optionally uses `DBIish`. I would like to write a few unit tests to ensure that the functionality is working. However, `DBIish` should be an *optional* dependency, meaning you don't need it to install or use the package. How can I skip `DBIish` tests if the user does not have `DBIish` installed?

Something like:

```
{
    require ::('DBIish');
    CATCH {
        default {
            skip-testing;
        }
    }
}
```

... would be ideal, but an optional test flag would also work, but I can't seem to find any documentation on the topic.

Comment: maybe you can go ```try {require ::('DBIish'); some tests} else {skip-testing}```

Comment: If it's about importing a class that should be installed (or not), I always use the following "trick":  `my \Foo = try "use Foo; Foo".EVAL`.  If it worked, then `Foo` will be the class.  If it didn't, then `Foo` will be `Nil`.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen That's exactly what i'm looking for I think, I would take that as an answer. Thanks!!

Comment: https://github.com/coke/raku-zef-deps/blob/main/t/png.t has an example of this that doesn't eval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's about importing a class that should be installed (or not), I always use the following "trick":

```
my \Foo = try "use Foo; Foo".EVAL;
```

If it worked, then `Foo` will be the class. If it didn't, then `Foo` will be `Nil`.

Comment: you need ```use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;``` for this

Comment: Actually, you don't need `use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL` for that.  The method version of `.EVAL` doesn't, the `sub` version does.

Comment: oh - that’s weird … is there a rationale for that - seems to me that we would want the I AM DOING SOMETHING BAD hint for both flavours…?

Comment: Yes, but this is very hard to implement, as methods are late bound.